# API is providing Ancillary data/Amenities along with search results in Sabre

Tags: sabre

What are the API is providing Ancillary data/Amenities along with search results. .Could you please advise me on how to get search results with enough ancillary product details( Ex: Wi-fi, Meals, Chargeable Seat ,Recline,Seat Width etc

Comment: Are you looking for flight and or hotel data?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to register at https://developer.sabre.com/product-catalog and from this environment you will have access to all the REST / SOAP web services made available by SABRE.

Once you have been granted access, you will receive a development credential with the list of authorized web services for your project.

If you do not have this credential, ask the Saber account executive or a travel agency that has this access.

There is a service below that will return the list of ancillaries you need to have the information requested.

- https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/search/get_ancillary_offers

This service depends on a token generated by SessionCreateRQ that needs a valid web credential, as informed above.

The services to be used are:

- SessionCreateRQ: This service generate a token to use in the flow
- GetReservantionRQ or TravelItineraryReadRQ: One of these service return the flight information to use in the ancillaryOffer
- GetGetAncillaryOffersRQ: This service inform ALL ancillay available in the flight requested.